# Merging three data frames with different common keys

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge three data frames A,B,C as below. DF A and B have a common key(imonum), DF B and C have a common key (id).

```
DF A    
imonum  name
2234    xyz
3445    abc
2234    xyz
3445    abc


----------


DF B    
imonum  id
2234    1
3445    2


----------
DF C    
id  mailid
1   email(xyz)
2   email(abc)
```

---

```
DF required     
imonum  name    mailid
2234    xyz email(xyz)
3445    abc email(abc)
2234    xyz email(xyz)
3445    abc email(abc)
```

---

How can i get the required data frame

Comment: Please let me know if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job,

```
merge_1 = pd.merge(A, B)
merge_2 = pd.merge(B, C)

final_merge = pd.merge(merge_1, merge_2)
```

Output -

|  | imonum | name | id | mailid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2234 | xyz | 1 | email(xyz) |
| 1 | 2234 | xyz | 1 | email(xyz) |
| 2 | 3445 | abc | 2 | email(abc) |
| 3 | 3445 | abc | 2 | email(abc) |